How control for the number of observations in the models?
Suppose we have two time series, namely, $Y^{(1)}$ and $Y^{(2)}$ with $n^{(1)}>>n^{(2)}$ observations, respectively (in other words, $Y^{(1)}$ has much more observations than $Y^{(2)}$). For each time series we estimate an AR(1) model and then we aim to compare the magnitudes of the coefficients:
$$Y^{(1)}_{t}=\alpha^{(1)}+\beta^{(1)}Y^{(1)}_{t-1}+\epsilon^{(1)}_{t},$$
$$Y^{(2)}_{t}=\alpha^{(2)}+\beta^{(2)}Y^{(2)}_{t-1}+\epsilon^{(2)}_{t},$$
and we want to determine $sgn(\hat{\beta}^{(1)}-\hat{\beta}^{(2)})$.
The complication with this simple problem is that the number of observations differ quite significantly, and it produces consistent differences between estimates of AR(1) coefficients. I estimated AR(1) models for a few thousand pairs of time series, and statistically confirmed that time series with shorter time series length have smaller coefficient than the longer counterparts, all things being equal (this result has been achieved through regression and random forest). For this pair above, we have $|\hat{\beta}^{(1)}>\hat{\beta}^{(2)}|$. Therefore, I want to somehow adjust AR(1) coefficients before making any comparisons.
One approach that I had off the top of my head is to adjust the corresponding coefficients by their standard errors, as the latter accounts for the number of observations.  In other words, the approach is to compute $\hat{\beta}^{(1)}/SE^{(1)}$ and $\hat{\beta}^{(2)}/SE^{(2)}$, and then determine $sgn(\hat{\beta}^{(1)}/SE^{(1)} - \hat{\beta}^{(2)}/SE^{(2)})$. However, this approach is not effective as standard errors (as one can expect) is smaller for longer time series, and less than 1. Therefore, relative to $\hat{\beta}^{(1)}$, $\hat{\beta}^{(1)}/SE^{(1)}$ is increasing much more, than $\hat{\beta}^{(2)}/SE^{(2)}$ compared to $\hat{\beta}^{(2)}$, implying that we increased the gap between coefficients more and still $sgn(\cdot)$ function yields the same results.
Questions:

What approach would you use to adjust AR(1) coefficients with respect to the number of observations?

How would you improve/modify the approach that I've described here to make it viable and effective?



"The complication with this simple problem is that the number of observations differ quite significantly, and it produces consistent differences between estimates of AR(1) coefficients." There is no clear reason why the length of the time series should have an influence on the model. Unless, some other things change as well. What changes with the time series other than their length? Like, is there a difference in frequency of sampling? Or do you just have statistical variations in your estimates which for longer time series might be more likely to contain some black swan outlier?

So the approach should be to start with a model. What does the AR(1) coefficient represent and how is it related to the time series length? Based on the model you can formulate a way to compare different observations.

Actually, my initial assumption was that sample size shouldn't affect the results, but I found strong, very strong pattern that it does explain heterogeneity in magnitude of coefficients across thousands of time series (for instance, in random forest, # of observations was the N1 predictor among other predictors). The reason behind this is the following (in my understanding): I am dealing with financial data, and longer time series implies different market regimes, more outliers, more shocks.

I am just estimating different AR(1) models for each time series, and then want to compare the coefficients of different AR(1) models. But as i described above, time series have different lengths, and therefore affect coefficient sizes. I want to control for this before comparing them.

The coefficient estimates are just the "best bet" for what the coefficients should be based on the data. The number of data points will not give useful information about any "adjustment" of them (because there is no reason to think that another estimator/coefficient value might be better based on the number of observations). The number of data points will play a role regarding the distribution of any test statistic (on which also confidence intervals may be based). So rather than doing adjustments to coefficients, you need to figure out these distributions if you want to run tests/CIs.

Chances are this can be theoretically elaborated, maybe it's not even difficult, but I don't have the time to do that, therefore this is just a comment, not an answer.

I don't claim that one coefficient is better than the other. I am claiming that, else being equal, the longer time series produces higher coefficient (again, I found statistically strong evidence). This is because, longer time series implies more outliers, different market regimes and high volatile episodes, and these are encompassed in long time series. Short time series do not capture these episodes, or capture to a lesser extent. ... I agree that each coefficient is the best bet, but this could be true when we deal with each coeff in isolation, but here we compare each other.

The thing is that standard theory will assume that you don't have "non-normal" outliers. If you want to have something that takes outliers into account, no "adjustment" based on standard theory (including standard error) will do. Also you'd need to specify what the role of outliers should be. Do you want to disregard them? Or if you want to take them into account and model them (chances are there are models that take high volatility phases into account, but not AR(1))? If you assume AR(1) and things happen that violate AR(1) grossly, you are in trouble.

I am dealing with empirical distributions, and non-normal outliers are observed in many episodes. Also, this is not only about outliers, but also about different market regimes, different volatility regimes, economic/market crises ... longer time series captures to a higher extent these patterns, than the shorter one; therefore, we have the statistically significant effect of # of observations on the magnitude of coeff across different time series (# of obs explains to a higher degree heterogeneity in coeff sizes).

I am not sure how to model those market patterns all together, therefore was thinking better somehow control for lengths of time series, to make them more comparable.

@ChristianHennig I think there is nothing wrong if i take $\hat{\beta}/SE$ instead of $\hat{\beta}$, right? Then the only problem here is the following: as longer series typically have bigger AR(1) coeff, and smaller SE (which is less than 1), compared to those of shorter time series, this transformation makes coefficients of longer time series bigger. This could be adjusted if SE is not less than 1 ... Do you think i can transform denominator to make it bigger than 1? E.g., maybe $\hat{Y}/(1+SE)$?

Comments are not for extended discussion. I have said that I don't think adjustment of coefficients will do the job well. Also chances are AR(1) is an inappropriate model. You are entitled to have a different opinion.

Why the different $n$'s? Different time resolution, or differetnt observation times?

Different $n$s because, I am dealing with different financial time series from different firms.

It is typical for averages of larger samples to statistically dominate.
$$P\left[X_0 > \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right] < 0.5$$
Namely, this happens for the many distributions that have the mean larger than the median, where  $$P[X > mean] = P[X > median] - P[mean > X > median] < 0.5$$
For example consider this example in r where we compare a sample of exponential distributed variables of size 1 and of size n. The mean of the larger sample will be 63% of the time larger.
set.seed(1)
n = 100
x = replicate(10^4, mean(rexp(n)) )
y = replicate(10^4,      rexp(1)  )
diff = x-y

mean(diff>0)  ### 0.6369

### for large values n it will approach
pexp(1)    ### 0.6321206

You could see the computation of a coefficient in an AR1 model as some sort of averaging process. So it will not be surprising if the effect happens there as well.
How to deal with this matter depends a bit on what sort of comparison you wish to make. And what the circumstances are.

Why do you make these binary comparisons and why is it a problem if you don't make the correction? In the example with the exponential distribution the difference is distributed as:

The average difference is zero, but you get more often a difference above zero than below zero. So you decide to make decisions based on whether $diff > 0$ or $diff < 0$ but why look at the sign only?

For larger samples both estimates should be approximately normal distributed, and if you still have a large discrepancy between large samples and small samples, then probably there is some effect where the large samples have a truly larger coefficient due the size of the samples correlating with other aspects (a spurious effect, because it is not causal in this case). It is not clear why you want to correct for size, but if it is because you wish to correct for those other aspects, then it might be better to focus on those other aspects more directly rather than the sample sizes.



Thanks a lot for this! Actually, I have many time series, for which I want to estimate AR(1) coefficients, and rank coefficients in ascending order. I don't care about $diff$, just for the convenience I have introduced that term in the question. The problem, as you described in your answer, is that when I rank coefficients, at the top cluster those which are obtained from short time series. And this pattern I've confirmed through regression and random forest (in RF, the most important factor was # of obs). Therefore, I am trying to apply some transformation (adjust by n), to avoid this issue.

Trying to make an example with an ar model where the errors are non-normal distributed, I notice that there is also a bias which differs with the size of the dataset.
